# Can I use LINQ To Search an inner list in a List of Lists?

Tags: c#, linq

I have these classes:

```
public class ZoneMember
    // a zone member is a member of a zone
    // zonemembers have ports, WWPNs, aliases or all 3
{
    private string _Alias = string.Empty;
    public string MemberAlias {get{return _Alias;} set{_Alias = value; } }
    private FCPort _Port = null;
    public FCPort MemberPort { get { return _Port; } set { _Port = value; } }
    private string _WWPN = string.Empty;
    public string MemberWWPN { get { return _WWPN; } set { _WWPN = value; } }
    private bool _IsLoggedIn;
    public bool IsLoggedIn { get { return _IsLoggedIn; } set { _IsLoggedIn = value; } }
    private string _FCID;
    public string FCID {get{return _FCID;} set{ _FCID=value; } }
}

public class Zone
{ 
    public List<ZoneMember> MembersList = new List<ZoneMember>();
    private string _ZoneName;
    public string zoneName{ get{return _ZoneName;}  set{_ZoneName=value;} }

    public Zone(string n) { zoneName=n; }
```

}

```
public class ZoneSet 
{    
    private string _ZoneSetName;
    private int _VSANNum;
    public string ZoneSetName{get{ return _ZoneSetName;}  set{_ZoneSetName=value;} }
    public int VSANNum{ get{ return _VSANNum;}  set{_VSANNum=value;} }
    public bool isActive;
    public List<Zone> ZoneList = new List<Zone>();
}
```

I want to find all the zones in a Zoneset that have a zone member with a specific value for a property in the MembersList.

I know something like this will work - in this case I am searching on the WWPN property:

```
// assumes myZoneSet has already been instantiated ad has zones in it
// and inputWWPN in the select statement has the value we want

List<Zone> myZoneList = new List<Zone>();

foreach (Zone z in myZoneset)
{   
var zm=null;

        zm = from member in z.MembersList where member.MemberWWPN == inputWWPN select member;  
  // if we find a matching member, add this zone to the list 
  if (zm != null)
   {  myZoneList.Add(z);
    }
}
```

Is there a way to use LINQ to do the entire thing?  I am not sure what the terminology would be in database terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this -

```
List<Zone> listOfZone = zoneSet.ZoneList.Where(e => e.Any(p => p.MemberWWPN == inputWWPN)).ToList();
```

Comment: Won't work, `e` cannot be defined in both the outer and the inner lambda.

Answer (score 3):

This small query should be all you need:

```
var myZoneList = myZoneSet.ZoneList
    .Where(z => z.Any(member => member.MemberWWPN == inputWWPN))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: thanks, I will test this out in the next day or so.  if it works, I have some other code to refactor and I think I can use this.

Answer (score 0):

```
 myZoneList =myZoneSet.SelectMany(z => z.MembersList).Where(m => m.MemberWWPN == "somestring").ToList();
```

I hope this will help.